# GoogleScript Mail Parser - Only retrieve emails for past X days

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

Built a basic email parser so that I can get in gSheet my emails, however though, I have > 50k emails and I only need to retrieve them for the past 7 days each time I'll run the parser. Looked around but weren't able to find any similar issue

This is the script I have

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

function getEmails() {
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("HOUSE_PHONELEAD");
  var inc = 100;
  var start = 0;
  var row = 2;
  var threads = label.getThreads();
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var messages=threads[i].getMessages();
    for (var m=0; m < messages.length; m++) {   
      sheet.getRange(row,1).setValue(messages[m].getPlainBody());
      row++;
      Utilities.sleep(1000);
    }
  }
}

function onOpen() {
  var menuEntries = [ {name: "Load Emails", functionName: "getEmails"} ];
  spreadsheet.addMenu("Email", menuEntries);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

> var threads = GmailApp.search('newer_than:7d');

instead of

> var threads = label.getThreads();

search method allow to pass a string query :
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#searchquery

the query string must be a gmail specific operator :

https://support.google.com/vault/answer/2474474?hl=en